# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'settings'

Tags: angular

I want `SettingsComponent` display inside `router-outlet` named `full-width`.

`app.component.html` :

```
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   <router-outlet name="full-width" ></router-outlet>
```

`app.routing.module.ts` :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'settings', 
    component: SettingsComponent, 
    outlet: 'full-width',
  },
];
```

Comment: Can you add all of error log in your question ? Please [edit] it :)

Answer (score 0):

in your html you can try:

```
<app-selector-for-settings-component name="full-width"></app-selector-for-settings-component>
```

instead of

```
<router-outlet name="full-width" ></router-outlet>
```

also in app.module.ts

in @NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [name_of_settings_component],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```